# Register.cshtml Submit Button does not work

Tags: c#, html, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've created an ASP.NET website and added custom fields to registration. When I try to submit my registration, my site does not get redirected, and I'm pretty sure although not certain the database has not been updated. What may cause this issue and how can I fix this?

```
<button id="registerSubmit" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Register</button>
```

I've added

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(InputModel=> InputModel.Input.UserProffesion,  Html.GetEnumSelectList<Proffesion>(), optionLabel: "Select a value")
```

which is an `enum` dropdownlist and I also added a gender field that I have yet to implement in `Register.cshtml` and 2 date fields that are automatically updated in `Mindfull8User.cs` (my identity schema inside `Mindfull8.Identity.Data.Minfull8User.cs` constructor.

Register.cshtml:

```
<form id="registerForm" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">

    <h2>Create a new account.</h2>
    <hr />
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" name="FirstName" aria-required="true" />
        <label asp-for="Input.FirstName">First Name</label>
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
     <div class="form-floating">
        <input asp-for="Input.LastName" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" name="LastName" aria-required="true" />
        <label asp-for="Input.LastName">Last Name</label>
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
     <div class="form-floating">
        <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" />
        <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" />
        <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="new-password" aria-required="true" />
        <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>             
       
        <div class="form-floating">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(InputModel=> InputModel.Input.UserProffesion ,  Html.GetEnumSelectList<Proffesion>(), optionLabel: "Select a value")
         </div>   
          
    <div class="form-floating">
    </div>
    <button id="registerSubmit" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Register</button>
</form>
```

`Register.cshtml.cs`:

```cs
namespace Mindfull8.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<Mindfull8User> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<Mindfull8User> _userManager;
        private readonly IUserStore<Mindfull8User> _userStore;
        private readonly IUserEmailStore<Mindfull8User> _emailStore;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<Mindfull8User> userManager,
            IUserStore<Mindfull8User> userStore,
            SignInManager<Mindfull8User> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userStore = userStore;
            _emailStore = GetEmailStore();
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
    ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
    /// </summary>
    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Max characters is 255")]
        [Display(Name = "FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Max characters is 255")]
        [Display(Name = "LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Gender")]
        public bool? Gender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Proffesion")]
        public Proffesion UserProffesion { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = CreateUser();

            user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
            user.LastName = Input.LastName;
            user.Email = Input.Email;
            user.Gender = Input.Gender;
            user.UserProffesion = Input.UserProffesion;

            await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
            await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                }
                else
                {
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
```

User Model:

```cs
public class Mindfull8User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime LastOnline { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public bool? Gender { get; set; }

    public Proffesion UserProffesion { get; set; }
    public enum Proffesion
    {
        Doctor,
        Paitent,
        Proffesor
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove the `returnUrl` parameter from the  `public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)` declaration. The data model already contains the `ReturnUrl` property. And see the following article: [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core: Write a basic form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#write-a-basic-form)

Comment: I think it's better of you to provide a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for helping troubleshoot

Comment: ` my site does not get redirected, and I'm pretty sure although not certain the database has not been updated` did you mean that the submit request had gone into your `onPost` method but met issue to insert a new row into the database? or something else?